# CGBitmapContextCreate returns nil on anything but an iPhone 4 photo

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, null, bounds, cgbitmapcontextcreate

I'm pretty sure this is a stupid coding error due to the fact i'm a bit of a newbie in iOS and especially on Quartz.

I have the following code - Which works on photos i've taken with my iPhone's camera, but it returns nil (in ctx) when im creating a context for any photo in different dimensions or landscape photos. I'm kinda not sure why this is happening, I'd love to hear your thoughts about this :)

Thanks in advance,
Shai.

```cpp
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, 1936, 2592);

CGImageRef imageRef = [self.filteredImage CGImage];
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);

int targetWidth = imageView.bounds.size.width;
int targetHeight = imageView.bounds.size.height;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef ctx;

if (self.filteredImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || self.filteredImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetWidth, targetHeight, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpace, bitmapInfo);

} else {
    ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetHeight, targetWidth, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpace, bitmapInfo);
}
```